# Show / Interactive / Visible ClosedXML Excel.XLWorkbook Without Saving

Tags: openxml, closedxml

Using `ClosedXML` is it possible to show a new `Excel.XLWorkbook()` in the GUI without first saving the file?

I am using VB .Net and moving from `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` to `ClosedXML` to take advantage of the increased speed.

In Excel Interop I can create a new `Excel.ApplicationClass` and choose whether to make Excel visible in the GUI by setting `.interactive` and `.visible` to `TRUE`.

Is there an equivalent for `ClosedXML` to show Excel in the GUI?

I cannot find anything in the `ClosedXML` library that would appear to affect application visibility.

**Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel:**

```
ExcelReport = New Excel.ApplicationClass

ExcelReport.Interactive = True 'True = Excel is interactive in the GUI
ExcelReport.Visible = True 'True = Excel is visible in the GUI
```

**ClosedXML:**

```
Dim wb = New Excel.XLWorkbook()
wb.Visible = True (no equivalent)
```

I know part of the beauty of `ClosedXML` is that Excel is not actually required to generate the file, however I would like the ability to debug and visualise the file inside Excel during creation/writing.

I would also like the end user to decide whether or not to save the file and if so where to save it.  Currently, using Excel Interop, the report is presented to to the end user in the GUI as an unsaved 'Book1' workbook.  They can interact with the excel report without saving, close it, save it somewhere else.

Is this possible using `ClosedXML`?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an equivalent for `ClosedXML` to show Excel in the GUI?

No, there is not. (Except when you write a complete new GUI for ClosedXML.)